# How do I solve this second order nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I want to solve the following equation:
$$
m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 - mg=0
$$
Where $m, g, b$ are constants. These are the initial conditions:
$$
x(0) = 0 \\
x'(0) = 0 \\
x''(0) = g
$$
Please help.

Comment: Try the substitution $p=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and recall
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right) =\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right) = p \frac{dp}{dx}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Not that this is only an equation of motion with air resistance as long as $\dot x>0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 - mg=0$$
Substitute $p=x'$:
$$mp'+ bp^2 - mg=0$$
$$p'=g-\dfrac  bmp^2 $$
It's separable.